# Python Pandas: Breaking a list or series into columns of different sizes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a single series with 2 columns that looks like

```
1   5.3
2   2.5
3   1.6
4   3.8
5   2.8
```

...and so on. I would like to take this series and break it into 6 columns of different sizes. So (for example) the first column would have 30 items, the next 31, the next 28, and so on. I have seen plenty of examples for same-sized columns but have not seen away to make multiple custom-sized columns.

Comment: All columns(series) of a dataframe have the same size.  Now, you could have NaN  as values at the end of the column, but the size of the column/series in a dataframe are equal.

Comment: Nan would be fine to fill in the blanks to make them equal but how would I place a Nan in the middle of my dataset? I still need different columns of different sizes somehow.

Comment: You can create independent series of differing lengths, but all columns of a datafame are equal length in pandas.  This is because the underlying structure of a datafame is a NxM numpy matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments you can try use the index of the series to fill your dataframe

```
s = pd.Series([5, 2, 1, 3, 2])
df = pd.DataFrame([], index=s.index)
df['col1'] = s.loc[:2]
df['col2'] = s.loc[3:3]
df['col3'] = s.loc[4:]
```

Result:

```
    col1  col2  col3
0   5.0   NaN   NaN
1   2.0   NaN   NaN
2   1.0   NaN   NaN
3   NaN   3.0   NaN
4   NaN   NaN   4.0
```